# Slow to send camera images via UDP

Tags: android, python, camera, udp, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to stream images from a Camera on my Raspberry Pi via UDP.  I'm receiving / displaying them on an Android device.

According to my calculations, my application sends at a maximum rate of 10fps, but I need 25 fps.

Does anyone know how to speed my solution up, or have a better solution?

My code is as follows

```
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.connect((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 30
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))
time.sleep(0.1)

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    image = frame.array
    img = Image.fromarray(image,'RGB')
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    img.save(output, format='JPEG')
    contents = output.getvalue()
    output.close()

    sock.send(contents)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    rawCapture.truncate(0)
sock.close
```

Comment: Please leave out begging and thanks from your posts (re-read the help->tour: no chit-chat). Your question ("Knows no better solution?") is unclear, you might want to rewrite that.

Comment: Hi, your question came to me in the "Help and Improvement" review queue. In particular I've: a) moved the android tagas this seems to be Python code to run on a R-Pi. I had to guess you're viewing the stream on an Android device - please edit again if not the case. b) edited the English a little - no problem if it's not your first language (lots of people same on here) but try to get the question precise. c) removed extra `'` in the code - probably typo was messing up code auto-colour. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel here. Are you trying to make an IP camera?  Implement [ONVIF streaming](http://www.onvif.org/specs/stream/ONVIF-Streaming-Spec-v210.pdf). See "5.1.4 JPEG over RTP" for JPEG over UDP format